# How would I remove parts of all list items in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

I’m fairly new to Python, but I figured that I’d give some HTML parsing a go. I’ve gotten to the point where I have a list of entries, but I don’t know how to get them to what I want to be. My input is

`['<li><span class=\'typeno\'>1.</span><a href="#m3_ds_real_save_file">M3 DS Real Save File</a></li>', '<li><span class=\'typeno\'>2.</span><a href="#incomplete_mario_kart_wii_course">Incomplete Mario Kart Wii Course</a></li>', '<li><span class=\'typeno\'>3.</span><a href="#shared_library_link_file">Shared Library Link File</a></li>', '<li><span class=\'typeno\'>4.</span><a href="#hacha_split_archive_file">Hacha Split Archive File</a></li>']`

and I want my output to be

`1. M3 DS Real Save File 2. Incomplete Mario Kart Wii Course 3. Shared Library Link File 4. Hacha Split Archive File`

My problem is I can’t find a way to do regex or similar to affect the HTML in the way I want to while also affecting each item in the list individually. It should also be noted that these entries change so I cannot hard code the changing. How would I do this? TIA!

Comment: I'd recommend you to lookup `BeautifulSoup` to do this kind of work.

Comment: please show your code, you probably don't need regex here, use the `BeautifulSoup` library to get the text from the `li` items while iterating over the same.

Comment: We're not supposed to add "me, too" comments, but you should pay attention to the above advice.  HTML pages tend to change dramatically over time, and regexes are nowhere near flexible enough to handle the variability.  Use an HTML parser like `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Before this I've never found the need for it, but it looks very useful for HTML parsing. I'll check it out for my other code as well, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you'll need [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = ['<li><span class=\'typeno\'>1.</span><a href="#m3_ds_real_save_file">M3 DS Real Save File</a></li>', '<li><span class=\'typeno\'>2.</span><a href="#incomplete_mario_kart_wii_course">Incomplete Mario Kart Wii Course</a></li>', '<li><span class=\'typeno\'>3.</span><a href="#shared_library_link_file">Shared Library Link File</a></li>', '<li><span class=\'typeno\'>4.</span><a href="#hacha_split_archive_file">Hacha Split Archive File</a></li>']
html =  ''.join([str(elem) for elem in data]) # turn data into a single html string for BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = [i.text.strip() for i in soup.find_all("li")]
```

Output `result`:

```
['1.M3 DS Real Save File', '2.Incomplete Mario Kart Wii Course', '3.Shared Library Link File', '4.Hacha Split Archive File']
```

If no other lists are present in your html you can directly feed the html into `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` without any preprocessing.